# Single checkbox to update multiple attributes Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

Working on a rails app. I want a single checkbox field in my edit view to set multiple attributes to nil when checked. Most people seem to have the opposite problem: they want multiple checkbox fields to save to one attribute.

My edit form looks like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "restaurant[weekday_closed_checkbox]", nil %>
<%= check_box_tag "restaurant[weekday_closed_checkbox]", "checked" %>
```

Weekday_closed_checkbox is a virtual attribute. It doesn't save to the database. To accommodate this, my Restaurant controller looks like this:

```
def update
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])

    if checkbox_params[:weekday_closed_checkbox] == "checked"
        @restaurant.weekday_open_at = nil
        @restaurant.weekday_close_at = nil
    end
    if @restaurant.update(restaurant_params)
        redirect_to @restaurant
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
# . . . 
private
    def restaurant_params
        params.require(:restaurant).permit(:id, :name, :description, ....)
    end
    def checkbox_params
        params.require(:restaurant).permit(:weekday_closed_checkbox)
    end
end
```

My restaurant model looks like this:

```
attr_accessor :weekday_closed_checkbox
```

When the edit view renders and I check the checkbox and submit, the params look as follows:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DNq3nbGLgPTcvdG3KF8mkyJxm3i0MlQs6TjBd6ylJHQ=", "restaurant"=>{"name"=>"Name", "description"=>"World's best restaurant", . . . "weekday_closed_checkbox"=>"checked"}
```

But the nil values do not get saved to the database.

The problem is not with the update action; other fields can edit and be saved without issue. Moreover, the issue goes away when I just use multiple checkboxes to set the attribute to nil. Can't figure out what's going wrong!

Comment: it is a full `update` action? because i can not see `save()` on record then records not updated in database.

Comment: Sorry, no; it's not a complete update action. I've only included the relevant bits. But the update action works, I am able to edit everything in the model except this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `update` isn't saving your manual (out of params) adjustments.

You either need to only manipulate the params, like

```
if checkbox_params[:weekday_closed_checkbox] == "checked"
    params[:restaurant].merge { 
      weekday_open_at: nil,
      weekday_close_at: nil }
end
```

or just do a save instead

```
@restaurant.attributes = restaurant_params
if @restaurant.save
    redirect_to @restaurant
else
    render 'edit'
end
```

But it would probably be best to do as a `before_save` in your model.

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this:

```
# _form.html.erb
<%= check_box_tag "restaurant[make_everything_nil]", "checked" %>
```

Then you get `params[restaurant][:make_everything_nil]`. In your controller, you can check the value of it:

```
# xxx_controller.rb
def update
  if params[restaurant][:make_everything_nil] == true
    # set all the values here
  end

  # the rest of logic here
end
```

Replace the actions with a more sensible name. I am just giving an example.